# Dont Include in wildcard search if blocked

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem here,

There are two users

The User 1 profile_id

```
3115267284
```

then the User 2 Profile_id

```
3028630039
```

there is a table named friends with a structure of

```
from_profile_id
to_profile_id
request
blocked_by
```

and this is the data and structure of users

```
var_id  profile_id  fullname             firstname   lastname
180     3115267284  John Louis Domincel  John Louis  Domincel  
181     3028630039  James Domincel       James       Domincel  
182     3450766778  asdasd asdsadas      asdasd      asdsadas
```

Lets say the data of that Friends table was

```
from_profile_id  to_profile_id  request  blocked_by
3028630039       3115267284     3        3115267284
```

I use this command to search data

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE fullname LIKE "%'.$s_final.'%" LIMIT 5
```

this is the preview

[image]

and I just want to make profile_id 2 which is 3028630039 will not be able to search profile_id 1 that is 3115267284 cause Profile id 1 is the one who blocked two but profile_id 1 will be able to search profile id 2

I have also tried using `JOIN` and `ISNOT()` but no success

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample an th expected  result

Comment: How do we know which profile_id is currently searching the data ? Is that available as an input parameter / variable ?

Comment: I've updated the question sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the variable name for the profile_id of the user performing the search is `$searcher_profile_id`.

You can use `Left Join` to join the two tables. Joining conditions are defined in a way to get the row corresponding to "blocked user". We need to consider only those users which are not blocked by using `WHERE .. IS NOT NULL`. This is sometimes referred to as "Anti-Join":

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN friends AS f 
  ON f.blocked_by = u.profile_id AND 
     f.blocked_by <> "' . (int)$searcher_profile_id . '" AND 
     (
      f.to_profile_id = "' . (int)$searcher_profile_id . '" OR 
      f.from_profile_id = "' . (int)$searcher_profile_id . '"
     ) AND 
     f.request = 3
WHERE u.fullname LIKE "%'.$s_final.'%" AND 
      f.from_profile_id IS NULL 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I'll try this one sir

Comment: It worked sir but, it shows that the person who blocked the user is the one who cannot search him and the profile that is being blocked can search the blocker

Comment: @JohnLouisDomincel from_profile_id is the one who has been blocked ? or the one who is doing the blocking ?

Comment: the from and to can do the blocking

Comment: @JohnLouisDomincel I have reversed the conditions. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It reversed too, 
when the user 1 is in from_profile it works
but when the user 1 is in to_profile it didnt

Comment: @JohnLouisDomincel final attempt. check the updated answer now pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183368/discussion-between-john-louis-domincel-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Comment: it works now but there is a little problem, the one who blocks the second person is also removed in the search lists

Comment: @JohnLouisDomincel why should it appear in the search. Isn't this the basic requirement of your question ?

Comment: Yes, but when the user 1 blocks the user 2, the name of user 1 was gone in the search in the user 1 and there was no problem now in the user 2 cause the name of the blocker was gone. the main problem is that, the name of the blocker was gone too on the blocker side.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could have someone blocked by multiple people I would query your SQL database in your php code and pull all blocked_by IDs for the user running the search. Then I would iterate through and do the check in the php code and stop the process if the ID being queried is in the list.

If you are really looking for efficiency this may not be the best solution. I suppose you could also run the query and then do the check in php so you aren't executing 2 queries.

Maybe someone else has a pure MySQL answer.

Comment: I'll try this one

Comment: Apologies; but I would seriously avoid this for an enterprise level software. This has serious scaleability issues. If the number of users blocked become too big, you will start hitting `max_packet_size` for `IN(..)`

Comment: I am right there with you on that Madhur. This was the quick fix.